# Send Job changes over email

Tags: jenkins

I can see in job page it shows the stories,bug fixes etc in changes tab. Is there a way to extract them and sen over email for each job?

Comment: Do you mean an email that is triggered after the job is complete or a button in the menu to send an email?

Comment: yes. to send the email after the job is complete having the details of changes deployed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [email-ext-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). It has the most customisation possibilities 
 of the mail plugins as far as I know, but it will require you to write some scripts.

If you go to `Add Post Build Action` and select `Editable Email Notification`, you will be able to configure the content of the email in details.

The default content can be configured in the advanced tab. You'll have to create a Groovy script to retrieve the information you want to put in the email. Groovy scripts are powerful in that you can hook into the Jenkins API itself to get any information you want or need. For more details refer to the doc of the plugin.

There are various templates to retrieve commonly used fields such as Changes. If the fields you want to extract are parts of external plugins, there is probably no example for them but they are available to Jenkins' Groovy as well.